# How to reload JS scripts from page in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, themes

I've tried redirecting to itself, changing the place of the scripts. If i manualy refresh, perfect, and if a navigate in the menus, it doesnt load.

The wp_enqueue_script function i tried but wasnt able to alter the already working scrripts, to be a collections of standalone, includable, script.

What i want is a simple reload function in php that forces the refresh, therefore, also reloading the javascript.

Thanks in advance.

The code looks like:

header
body
.
.
.
<<< Start of my page >>>>>>
.
.
.

XXXXX HTML/PHP code XXXXXX
.
.
.

...

...

.
.
.
<<< End of my page >>>>>>
.
.
.
end of body
footer
etc

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Is the Javascript related to a drop down menu? Can you post some code?

Comment: No, is a common load of another wordpress page. The problem is that I cant seem to be able to reload, the JS scripts, after i've been redirected by the wordpress. the redirection is made by a common, <a href="XXXXXX">. The problem iss that no js loads.